# Check for unique elements

Tags: r

just a simple question. 
I have a data frame(only one vector is shown) that looks like:

> cln1
>      A
>      b
>      A
>      A
>      c
>      d
>      A
>   ....

I would like the following output:

> cln1
>      b
>      c
>      d

In other words I would like to remove all items that are replicated. The functions "unique" as well as "duplicated" return the output including the replicated element  represented one time. I would like to remove it definitively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `setdiff` for that :

```
R> v <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5)
R> setdiff(v, v[duplicated(v)])
[1] 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `count` from the `plyr` package to count the occurences of an item, and delete all who occur more than once.

```
library(plyr)
l = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7)
count_l = count(l)
  x freq
1 1    1
2 2    1
3 3    2
4 4    1                                                                           
5 5    1                                                                           
6 6    2                                                                           
7 7    1  
l[!l %in%  with(count_l, x[freq > 1])]
[1] 1 2 4 5 7
```

Note the `!`, which means `NOT`. You of course put this in a oneliner:

```
l[!l %in%  with(count(l), x[freq > 1])]
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `plyr`, you should be able to do the same thing with `data.frame(table(l))`, I think.

Comment: Why wouldn't anyone not want to use plyr ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `table`:

With @juba's data:

```
as.numeric(names(which(table(v) == 1)))
# [1] 3 4 5
```

For OP's data, since its a character output, `as.numeric` is not required.

```
names(which(table(v) == 1))
# [1] "b" "c" "d"
```